# Using a sampling of a datetime index to select the features (rows) in a pandas dataframe at those datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a datetime index object that consists of the index values of randomly sampled data from a LARGER dataframe on which I am training a learner. I'd like to use the date time index e.g.

```
DatetimeIndex(['1911-11-18', '2015-05-02', '1934-08-15', '1950-09-16',
               '1944-06-01', '2004-07-30', '1947-11-18', '1977-07-08',
               '1945-05-31', '1944-01-31',
               ...
               '1884-06-24', '1999-11-22', '1960-02-02', '1883-03-08',
               '1952-11-19', '1993-02-04', '1965-04-26', '1885-09-30',
               '1890-02-26', '2008-03-28'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=300000, freq=None)
```

of each training example to go back to the full data frame and look up the target value on those days, AND THEN go 1 year into the future from that date to use as the real target.

The overall context is training on a random sample from time series data, and targeting a value in the future.

My big data frame is called toLearn. And the sample dataframe on which I am training is called dataSlice (a subset of toLearn).

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following works for what I was trying to do.

```
 # Find Target 7 years after Each Training Sample 

indicesOfTrainSamples=trainSamples.index
indicesOfTarget=indicesOfTrainSamples + pd.Timedelta(weeks=7*52)

targets=[]
for i in indicesOfTarget:
     targets.append(toLearn.loc[i])

targetSlices=pd.DataFrame(targets,index=indicesOfTarget)
targetFeature=targetSlices['targetValues']
```